# Is there a way to get alerts when a certain config or policy stops applying to devices on intune

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

Is there a way to get alerts when a certain config or policy stops applying to devices on intune?
is there any way this can be done by Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You can getting [started](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples) from here.

- [DeviceConfiguration_Get.ps1](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/DeviceConfiguration#4-deviceconfiguration_getps1): This will get you all the device configuration policies from the Intune Service that you have authenticated with.
- [CompliancePolicy_Export.ps1](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/CompliancePolicy#3-compliancepolicy_exportps1): This will get you all the compliance policies from the Intune Service that you have authenticated with. The script will then export the policy to .json format in the directory of your choice.